# EXCEL VBA - Using an If/Then Loop to Calculate Adjacent Cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I think/hope I am close to correct on building these loops. Essentially I have two columns with different IDs associated with fees being paid. I need to mask the IDs but they are text and not numeric so the only way I could think to do that was with the following loop.

It isn't working yet. The code runs and I think it is close but I must be missing something obvious because nothing is populating in the adjacent cell. Any ideas on how I can tweak this to make it happen?

```
       Sub Mask_Account()

Dim Sh As Worksheet

Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fee Letter Formatted")
Columns(3).EntireColumn.Insert
Columns(6).EntireColumn.Insert

Dim rcell As Range, rng As Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fee Letter Formatted").Range("B6:B200")
   For Each rcell In rng.Cells
   If Not IsError(rcell.Value) Then
      If rcell.Value <> "" Then
      rcell(0, 1).Formula = "=""****-*"" & right(rcell,3)"
      End If
    End If
               Next rcell


Dim rcell2 As Range, rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fee Letter Formatted").Range("D6:D200")
   For Each rcell2 In rng2.Cells
      If Not IsError(rcell2.Value) Then
      If rcell2.Value <> "" Then
      rcell2(0, 1).Formula = "=""****-*"" & right(rcell2,3)"
      End If
      End If
   Next rcell2

'Sheets("Fee Letter Formatted").Range("B,D").EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

The answer below takes care of most of the problems, I also ran into a problem because D can be a few different values. It can be " " or it can be "Same as Enrolled Account" I tried to modify it with the following but now the code runs but doesnt do anything.

```
For i = 1 To UBound(dArr)
    If Not IsError(dArr(i, 1)) Then
        If dArr(i, 1) <> "Same as Enrolled Account" Then
        dArr(i, 1) = dArr(i, 1)
        ElseIf dArr(i, 1) <> " " Then
        dArr(i, 1) = dArr(i, 1)
        ElseIf dArr(i, 1) <> "" Then
        dArr(i, 1) = "=""****-*""&right(" & Chr(34) & dArr(i, 1) & Chr(34) & ",3)"
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: "It isn't working yet," is a pretty vague way to put it. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Lots of issues: `Range("C,E")` and `Range("B,D")` are not valid range references, missing two `End If`s, and your quotes are off: `"=""****-*""&" & Right(rcell, 3)`

Comment: Also `Range("B1:B:200")` needs fixing

Comment: I modified the errors(I think) where I am struggling right now is it is giving me a type mismatch when testing if the cell value is unequal to blank.

Also the deletion of the columns is also failing.

Comment: @BigBen Hey BigBen, thank you for that help, I got all the errors fixed, but now it is giving me a type mismatch of the ```if <> ""``` statement. I edited my code in my main post to show what I am using now.

Comment: Add an outer `If Not IsError(rcell.Value) Then` to check that the cell is not an error value, and also add the necessary `End If`. Your quotes are still off btw.

Comment: I am so sorry, that doesn't make sense to me. does that go around the whole loop?

Comment: Put `If Not IsError(rcell.Value) Then` on a new line immediately before `For Each rcell In rng.Cells`, and add another `End If` on a new line after the existing `End If`.

Comment: When I added that I now get RunTime - Object Required on that line of code.

Comment: Declare `Dim rcell As Range` and BigBen meant **after** the first `For Each...` line.

Comment: Perfect! So now the code runs without errors but it still doesnt put the output in the adjacent cell. (Updated main code up top)

Comment: Hey there another problem came up that I addressed at the bottom of my original post. Any thoughts on how to potentially fix that?

Comment: @Wallenbees try updated code below, always be upfront with data values you are working on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Sub maskID()
Dim bArr, dArr
Dim i As Long

bArr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fee Letter Formatted").Range("B6:B200").Value
dArr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fee Letter Formatted").Range("D6:D200").Value

For i = 1 To UBound(bArr)
    If Not IsError(bArr(i, 1)) Then
        If bArr(i, 1) <> "" Or bArr(i, 1) <> "Same as Enrolled Account" Or bArr(i, 1) <> " " Then
            bArr(i, 1) = "=""****-*""&right(" & Chr(34) & bArr(i, 1) & Chr(34) & ",3)"
        End If
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To UBound(dArr)
    If Not IsError(dArr(i, 1)) Then
        If dArr(i, 1) <> "" Or dArr(i, 1) <> "Same as Enrolled Account" Or dArr(i, 1) <> " " Then
            dArr(i, 1) = "=""****-*""&right(" & Chr(34) & dArr(i, 1) & Chr(34) & ",3)"
        End If
    End If
Next i

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Progress").Range("B6:B200").Value = bArr
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Progress").Range("D6:D200").Value = dArr
End Sub
```